# "Select" event for firefox extension (on android)

Tags: android, firefox-addon

I try to make extension for firefox (android version)

I need get text selection when user makes long press.

I have such code:

```
.....
Services.obs.addObserver(this, "Gesture:LongPress", false);
.....

observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
    if (aTopic == "Gesture:LongPress") {
        var xw = this._xulWindow;
        var document = xw.BrowserApp.selectedBrowser.contentDocument;
        var selectedText = document.getSelection().toString();
        var prompts = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPromptService);
        prompts.alert(null, "ColorDict", selectedText);
    }
}
....
```

But I get empty alert. Because word will selected after LongPress handler finished.
How can I get selected word after user makes long press?

Comment: Is it about a regular text selection or selection inside an input field?

Comment: Not inside an input field. It is about selection on page (content)

Comment: izumeroot, have you finished your colordict extension?

Comment: Sorry, no. I try to read without dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very interesting. I insert

```
Services.obs.addObserver(this, "*", false);
```

istead

```
Services.obs.addObserver(this, "Gesture:LongPress", false);
```

and it works!! I see alert with selected word!

I will search a reason in documentation. Thanks!